# How to have some data of a firebase document editable only by user with "admin" status?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my angular app, I'm using firestore to store the profile of my user. Currently I've something like this:

/profiles/{uid}/:

```
{
    displayName: "Luigi",//--> Only editable by Luigi
    email: "luigi@mario.com",
    favoriteIceCream: "cookie dough",
    roles: {//--> Not editable by Luigi, only by people with admin role
        admin: true,
        user: true
    }
}
```

Is there a way to configure my firestore rules to only allow somebody that has the role "admin=true" to update the role object? And then the other informations should be only editable by the user in question(that I know doing)

Comment: @Dharmaraj Not really, because i need that "Luigi" can edit its profile, except the role part that can only be changed by somebody with an admin role. I'm not sure I can have rules for part of the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `request.resource` object to check which fields are being updates and check if the user is an admin if `roles` is being updated:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isAdmin() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/profiles/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles.admin == true;
    }
    
    match /profiles/{userId} {
      allow update: if request.auth != null && 
      ((request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasAny(['roles']) && isAdmin()) ||
      ((!request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasAny(['roles']) && request.auth.uid == userId)));
    } 
  }
}
```

If `roles` key is being updated, the above rules will check is the user is admin else if `roles` key is not being updated, it'll allow the user to update the document.

You can read more about `hasAny()` in [prevent some fields from being changed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#preventing_some_fields_from_being_changed) section of the documentation.

Comment: I didn't know about affectedKeys, seems a nice solution. We finally changed a bit our role structure, but this seems a nice approach.